# How to use svelte in an exising project?

Tags: javascript, svelte, rollupjs

I'm new to `svelte` and I'm trying to use it in my existing project following [this](https://davidtang.io/2020-01-22-adding-svelte-3-to-an-existing-application/) tutorial. So in svelte's `main.js` I outputs `css` and `js` like this:

```
export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: '/path/to/myapp/static/js/svelte-bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        svelte({
            compilerOptions: {
                // enable run-time checks when not in production
                dev: !production
            }
        }),
        // we'll extract any component CSS out into
        // a separate file - better for performance
        css({
            output: '/path/to/myapp/static/css/svelte-bundle.css'
        }),
```

However after `npm run dev` I get this error:

```
svelte-app@1.0.0 dev
rollup -c -w
rollup v2.56.3
bundles src/main.js → ../static/js/svelte-bundle.js...
[!] (plugin css) Error: The "fileName" or "name" properties of emitted files must be strings that are neither absolute nor relative paths, received "/path/to/myapp/static/css/svelte-bundle.css".
Error: The "fileName" or "name" properties of emitted files must be strings that are neither absolute nor relative paths, received "/path/to/myapp/static/css/svelte-bundle.css".
    at error (/path/to/myapp/svelte-components/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:151:30)
    at FileEmitter.emitFile (/path/to/myapp/svelte-components/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:13119:24)
    at Object.generateBundle (/path/to/myapp/svelte-components/node_modules/rollup-plugin-css-only/dist/index.cjs.js:84:12)
    at /path/to/myapp/svelte-components/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:20218:25
```

I have also added the scripts to myapp's html:

```
<link href="/static/css/svelte-bundle.css" />
<script defer src="/static/js/svelte-bundle.js"></script>
```

Also in browser I get:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/svelte-bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Apprecite your help to fix this.

Comment: Try to use a relative filename for the css plugin like `output: 'static/css/svelte-bundle.css'`.

Comment: This removes error, but now the bundes are created in `/path/to/myapp/svelte-components/static/js` instead of what I inteded which is `/path/to/myapp/static/js` and  `/path/to/myapp/static/css`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Weird I don't see any `svelte-components` in your rollup config. Do you have defined it somewhere in your code base?